# Spyder IDE output window doesnot clears the screen

Tags: python-3.x

When I use `os.system("clear")` in order to refresh the screen, the Spyder IDE doesn't clears the screen whereas an online compiler does it using same code. why?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are not using linux since this doesn't work, so for Windows usw `os.system('cls')`.